# What is the wrong with this function to enqueue the scripts and styles to the theme?

Tags: php, functions

```
     function custom_scripts_css_with_jquery()
{

    //wp_register_script( 'Bootstrap_min_js','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js',null, null, true);
    wp_register_script( 'select2jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js',null, null, true );
    wp_register_style( 'select2mincss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css', null, null, true );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2mincss' );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'Bootstrap_min_js');


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_css_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: You tell us, what isn't working

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE! Please add explanation to your question, and elaborate what is the expected behavior, and the unexpected behavior you are experiencing with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things I would change:

1. You're including a version of jQuery that is different than the one that is included with WordPress. You should de-register the WP version first so that aren't 2 copies/versions of jQuery loaded on the page
2. select2jquery should have jquery as a dependency so that you make sure is loaded after jQuery
3. The 3rd parameter of [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) if you're not using should be by default an empty array
4. The last parameter of [wp_register_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) is expecting the media for which this stylesheet has been defined and by default is 'all' (you're passing a boolean true).

I would change to this:

```
function custom_scripts_css_with_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
    wp_register_script( 'select2jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js',array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_register_style( 'select2mincss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' );  // the rest of parameters are the default

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2mincss' );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'Bootstrap_min_js');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_css_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: To add to this: while I can understand wanting to load jQuery from Google's CDN instead of the local site, it's a really bad idea to change the version from whatever is bundled with WordPress.

Comment: its working in custom template but now its not working in custom cutom add menu page @dbeja

Comment: its working in custom template but now its not working in custom add menu pages in admin panel @dbeja

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What should it do that it isn't doing?